# Is it possible to access the share functionality of a browser through a button click on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to share some information from my website. I managed to get it to share on facebook, however I would like to update this functionality and be able to call the share function available in the browser. Something like in the following image using the google chrome browser on my android phone.

[image]

I have tried using [Navigator.share](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share) and [ng-navigator-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-navigator-share)

However I was not able to set up Navigator.share and I kept receiving errors that my browser is not supported with ng-navigator-share (even thou it states that it supports google chrome on an android phone). Does anyone have any idea how this can be achieved.

Comment: *"I have tried using Navigator.share"* Please show us that. Also, did you ensure that you were using a [secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts)?

Comment: I decided not to go with Navigator.share and am currently trying to figure out how to get it to work with ng-navigator-share, if that code helps I will post it.